# Show VIM's listchars only on selected area

Tags: vim, highlight, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to setup VIM to act like any other editor and show special characters (tabs, spaces) only on selected text area, like this:

[image]

[image]

If I set this in my `.vimrc`:

```
set list
set listchars=tab:——,trail:⋅,nbsp:⋅
```

special characters will get visualized all over the file. My question is: How can I show special chars like in the images I attached? (only the selected area)

Answer (score 1):

From `:help 'list'`:

> ```
> 'list'            boolean (default off)
>                   local to window
> ```

Vim doesn't implement a scope that is limited to certain lines or the selection. **What you want is not possible.** The best you can do is work around this, e.g.:

- Always have `'list'` turned on, but choose the colors in such a way that the characters are only visible when there's a different background color (i.e. where the selection is active).
- Create two additional window splits around the selection, and only enable `'list'` in the middle one. This only works for a static selection, and you cannot navigate any more.

Comment: How would I do the first option? How can I choose fg/bg colors based on current color?

Comment: Doing that dynamically would be difficult. I meant to choose a black foreground color for `SpecialKey` (if you have a black background). Then, the listchars wouldn't be visible with the default background, only if the gray selection is active.

Comment: I would recommend against any such workarounds; the approach of toggling as per Peter Rincker's answer is more natural in Vim.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do such a thing. I find that it is usually hard to try and mold Vim to be like other editors. A more vim-like approach would be to setup a mapping to toggle `'list'` maybe something like this

```
nnoremap col :set list!<cr>:set list?<cr>
```

This mapping will toogle the `'list'` option via `col` (read change option list). This mapping and many more helpful ones are provided by Tim Pope's [Unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin.

Comment: I could fallback to this, if nothing else appears on here, but this is absolutely and completely not what I'm looking/asking for :(